# retrieving subsites from parent web using REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, rest

I am trying to get all subsites from a parent web using REST API. I tried following query which shows "The page cannot be found".

mysite/_api/web/parentWeb/webs

Answer (score 11):

Suppose, your site url is like this: `http://yourcompany.com/sites/projects`

Then in order to get sus site under projects site use:

```
http://yourcompany.com/sites/projects/_api/web/webs
```

Suppose you have site under projects named "Project1" and you want to find subsite under it, then use:

```
http://yourcompany.com/sites/projects/Project1/_api/web/webs
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately the url can be changed. I wanted to get all siblings by going up one step and get all subsites.

Answer (score 6):

The following REST endpoint

```
/_api/site/rootWeb/webinfos
```

will return the collection of sub webs (`WebInfo` objects) under root web

### Using Search REST API

The following REST query demonstrates how to find all webs under the specified path:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='path:https://contoso.sharepoint.com/*'&refinementfilters='contentclass:equals("STS_Web")'
```

Comment: thanks, this piece of code is running almost everywhere and I want to get all siblings by going up only one step and get all subsites.

Comment: Medes,in that case you could utilize search based approach in order to return all webs, the answer has been updated.

Comment: yes, still I need to have a dynamic value of "Path"? am I right?

Comment: it depends, you could specify site collection path (static), or if needed to return results relative to specific parent web, then path should be constructed (dynamic)

Comment: Vadim, I tested your query but it didn't work,

Comment: Could you please share the error details, just tested both REST queries, it works for me

Comment: I just replaced the path with the url of my root web and added the query to the end of a sub site like this (siteurl/and modified query) and I run it on browser it says the webpage cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

For up to date list (contrary to search) that also works for users with read-only permissions (contrary to /_api/web/webs), use this REST api:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/GetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser(nWebTemplateFilter=-1,nConfigurationFilter=-1)
```